# Sqlite Node module outputs wrong column

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, database, sqlite

I am making a simple Discord bot with Node and I'm having an issue with Sqlite module.
My sqlite database definition looks like this:

```sql
create table rooms
(
    id integer not null
        constraint rooms_pk
            primary key autoincrement,
    channel_snowflake integer not null,
    owner_snowflake integer not null
);

create unique index rooms_channel_snowflake_uindex
    on rooms (channel_snowflake);

create unique index rooms_id_uindex
    on rooms (id);

create table room_users
(
    room_id integer not null
        constraint room_users_rooms_id_fk
            references rooms
            on update restrict on delete cascade,
    user_snowflake integer not null
);
```

And I have the following data in my database:
[image: Database data]
I need to execute this query to get IDs of the channel owner and its members:

```sql
select owner_snowflake, room_users.user_snowflake
from rooms
         left join room_users on rooms.id = room_users.room_id
where channel_snowflake = '702042586092667000'
```

When I execute it in the database, I get the following (corrrect) result:
[image: Query results]
But when I try to execute the same query in Node, I get different results:
Here is my code:

```js
rows = await db.all(`select owner_snowflake, room_users.user_snowflake
                     from rooms
                       left join room_users on rooms.id = room_users.room_id
                     where channel_snowflake = '702042586092667000'`);
console.log(rows);
```

And the results I get are as follows:

```json
[
  { owner_snowflake: 255371734771826700, user_snowflake: 1 },
  { owner_snowflake: 255371734771826700, user_snowflake: 423 },
  { owner_snowflake: 255371734771826700, user_snowflake: 5675 }
]
```

As you can see, the results are different and Sqlite module outputs channel_snowflake instead of owner_snowflake.
Am I missing something? How can I fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: Changing a row in the database seems to have fixed the issue. Is it somehow connected with Sqlite caching data?

Comment: It's probably related to those numbers being too large to represent exactly in javascript. -- Indeed, entering  255371734771826688 into a javascript console gives back 255371734771826700.

Comment: Yes, changing the type to text solved the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the issue is that these snowflake IDs are too big for JavaScript to be stored without losing precision. (See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin) for more info.)

Changing the type of the IDs to "text" solves the issue